# Activity A starts Activity B, how to close Activity A

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I seem to be here quite a bit!!

I know this question has been asked already on here and in other places and I have tried to implement answers posted but it's not working for me

I have an activity, (`Activity A`) based on an if statement, it starts `Activity B`.  My problem is `Activity  A` keeps running, and in `Activity  A` I play an alarm and vibrate the phone, both keep going and while `Activity B` starts and runs (I can see in the logcat) it never comes to the front because of that.

Here is my code of my if statement

```
        if (dynamicActivation > threshold) {

                    alarmHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            CharSequence text = "YOUR CHILD HAS TRAVELLED OUTSIDE PROXIMITY";
                            Context context = getApplicationContext();
                            proximityAlert = Toast.makeText(context, text,
                                    duration);
                            proximityAlert.show();
                            alarmSound.start();
                            //v.vibrate(3000);

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                                openMaps();

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

And here is the code from the `openMaps()` function

```
public void openMaps() {

    Class track = ParentReal.class;
    Intent PRealIntent = new Intent(this, track);

    PRealIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
    startActivity(PRealIntent);

    ANN.this.finish();


}
```

I should add in case it causes problems is that there is another activity, a menu, once a button is clicked it opens `Activity A`...should I be closing the menu activity as well once I start `Activity A`?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I'm not to sure why the downvote, but I'll try and explain my problem, I have three activities A, B, C.  A is my menu, upon button click it starts Activity B, in activity B, based on the outcome of an if statement Activity C is started.

The problem is C runs, the processes can be see in the logcat but doesn't open.  B continues to play the alarm and vibrate and then the phone stalls and the alarm and vibrate continue.  I have the code for the if statement above and the code for the openMaps() function as well, this is called based on the outcome of the if, in which I try to open Activity C and close B

I hope that is clearer ;)

**ANOTHER EDIT**

ok, I have an idea what the problem is, I just don't know how to solve it.  I have a thread, inside that thread is an infinate while loop, inside this infinite while loop I check the distance between two coordinates (i want them constantly updating).

The problem is, variables I have declared globally are initialized within the loop so I have to run my if statement within that, to access those...I tried using a boolean 'test' that if it's true execute the if statement then set test to false but that doesn't work I'm afraid.

here's my code

```
Thread dist = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            while (true) {

                child = new Location("point A");

                child.setLatitude(Clatitude);
                child.setLongitude(Clongitude);

                parent = new Location("point B");

                parent.setLatitude(Platitude);
                parent.setLongitude(Plongitude);

                distance = child.distanceTo(parent);
                DisRound = 550;
                dynamicActivation = DisRound * weight;                          

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    if (test)
                    {
                        if(dynamicActivation > threshold)
                        {
                            finish();
                            new Timer().schedule(new MapsTimer(), 5000);
                            test = false;                               
                        }   
                        Log.d("ACTIVATION", Boolean.toString(test));
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    dist.start();
```

and heres the MapsTimer task

```
private class MapsTimer extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                CharSequence text = "YOUR CHILD HAS TRAVELLED OUTSIDE PROXIMITY";
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                proximityAlert = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                proximityAlert.show();
                alarmSound.start();                 

                openMaps();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am calling finish within the if statement.  I've been at this for 10 hrs now and it's melting my head, I'm sure it's simple, but only when you know how!!

Regards, 
Gary

Comment: before moving activity A to B use finish statement.

Comment: You post a `Runnable` which is running on the UI Thread (main thread) and in that `Runnable` you sleep for 5 seconds. At least, from the code you posted, I'm assuming that the code is running in the UI thread. That is bad. You don't want to block the UI thread for 5 seconds. Also, vibration and sounds won't block an `Activity` from coming to the front of the display. Look at your logcat, there are probably other indications there of troubles. Don't filter the logcat, you can miss important stuff that way.

Comment: thank you David, I've changed my code slightly, I know what the problem is, I'm just unsure how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for all your help, I sorted it myself.  I just inserted a break in the while loop.  As follows:

```
Thread dist = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            while (true) {

                child = new Location("point A");

                child.setLatitude(Clatitude);
                child.setLongitude(Clongitude);

                parent = new Location("point B");

                parent.setLatitude(Platitude);
                parent.setLongitude(Plongitude);

                distance = child.distanceTo(parent);

                // DisRound = Math.round(distance * 100.0) / 100.0;
                DisRound = 550;

                dynamicActivation = DisRound * weight;                          

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                        if(dynamicActivation > threshold)
                        {   
                            proximityAlert.show();
                            alarmSound.start(); 
                            new Timer().schedule(new MapsTimer(), 5000);
                            break;                          
                        }   
                        Log.d("ACTIVATION", Boolean.toString(test));

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            finish();
        }
    });
    dist.start();
```

So once the alert is shown, the alarm is played, and the mapsTimer is called, it breaks out of the infinite loop, it isn't needed any more and then I call finish();

Answer (score 1):

Your question and your code are not clear, but in general after the code which switch you to activity B you should call finish() which finish activity A

Comment: you can see from my code that I call finish(), but unfortunately it doesn't, so I need to know what I'm doing wrong, or what I can do to rectify it, if anyone can help it would be great